# Chart with audible sounds pronounced, for Proto-Indo-European?

Tags: proto-indo-european, resource-request, online-resources

Are there any counterparts like [this IPA Chart with Sounds](http://www.internationalphoneticalphabet.org/ipa-sounds/ipa-chart-with-sounds/), but for [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_phonology) (at least PIE's phonemes)?

Comment: @AlexB. Yes; forgive my puerility with PIE.

Answer (score 3):

No. Native speakers have been in short supply for the past few millenia. What you can do is decide what phonetic (IPA) value you want to assign to e.g. "p" and listen to that via an authoritative online supplier (also in short supply), or as exemplified in a real language. In picking phonetic values for PIE, you can never determine exact values for /i u e/, for instance (why, is a separate question). You have some major choices regarding "b" (which could be [p'] according to some) and "p" which might be [pʰ] according to some). You are totally on your own with the laryngeals. I suggest that a better and prior question is "what were the IPA phonetic values of the PIE segmental inventory".